# What does 'Locale not supported by C' mean?

Tags: gnome-terminal, locale

```
marco@marco-laptop:~$ onboard

(python:3065): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

I am using keyboard on the desktop (long story) from the terminal and usually nothing happens, only the keyboard appears, but after the application "computer janitor" started  (and I erased something) I see this notice.

What does it mean?

Comment: Do you mean a virtual keyboard when you say "keyboard on the desktop" ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a warning about locales.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale